# Android application with its own keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on application which deals with ancient language "Coptic language" which is not included in the android keyboard languages , so how to make private keyboard to the application ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are some issues surrounding it. But generally you must be able to do it.

Recently I faced similar issue, in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185238/how-to-add-custom-inputmethodservice-to-activity) of mine.

First, you need to make sure to set the [input method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputMethod) to the respective TextView. Or leave it as a service to be set in the system settings. The first option is better. But there is, of course, a limitation. The user won't be able to use any other keyboard of his liking while at this specific view.

Second, for specific implementation, you can see this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615).

Hope this helps.

P.S. There is one more [hacky way](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm), but it is not recommended.

Comment: Thank, I'll go for the first solution